# WebApi: Get api/Record/id/Tags

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-1.1

In my ASP.NET MVC (6) web Web Api I have

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Record")]
public class RecordController : Controller
{

    // ...

    // GET: api/Record/5
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRecord")]
    public async Task<Record> Get(string id)
    {
        var record = await repository.GetAsync<Record>(id);            
        return record;
    }
```

Now, my `Record` contains some `Tags`.

I would like to return these tags via     `api/Record/5/Tags`

How should I write my action in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it is a property on the record create a route template to match the desired route and return the tags when called

```
[HttpGet("{id}/Tags")] // GET: api/Record/5/Tags
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTags(string id) {
    var record = await repository.GetAsync<Record>(id);
    if(record == null) return NotFound();
    return Ok(record.Tags);
}
```

Comment: should a WebApi returning JSON return NotFound() or Ok() ?